# How can I raise the bottom chord of an engineered shed roof truss?

Tags: wood, ceiling, shed

I need to gain 3 inches of clearance underneath the ceiling joist underlined in blue. The entire joist is 24 feet across.

Is there a way for me to safely move this joist up a few inches and still transfer the force to the vertical beam?

If moving the entire joist up is too much, is it feasible to gain a few inches of clearance for a 5 foot span? How can I remove material but reinforce what is remaining in such a way to keep the required strength?

**Edit RE XY Problem:** I need more clearance for a tractor to fit underneath. Letting enough air out of the tires isn’t an option.

[image: Shed roof construction]

Comment: This is really something what you want a local engineer to advise on, not some idiot online.  Moving/cutting that roof trust will most likely end up with you wearing the roof, if not done right.  Most of those roof beams are usually made to close to minimum safety size, for cost savings.  They are not made bigger so people can cut pieces out of them.

Comment: Imagine you want to move something underneath it.  Would it be possible to lower it, maybe letting air out of tires?

Comment: It is very doable except for DIY. You need an engineer or an experienced contractor who has done that before.

Comment: I agree with the others here, as much as we hate to say it on a DIY site, it's time to hire a pro.

Comment: Just a nit-pick. Vertical is "post", horizontal is "beam". You have a row of vertical posts supporting the ends of your engineered trusses (in the main span) and sloping beams (in the side span). Also, in agreement that you need an engineer to tell you how to modify that truss to gain more clearance and the answer is most likely going to be "lower the floor".

Comment: Might be cheaper to shim every post and add an extra row of siding on the bottom...

Comment: TBH, this looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Maybe edit to tell us _why_ you need that extra 3" and we might help you come up with an alternate solution that's less involved than "rebuild half the structure".

Comment: I saw your edit. I presume there's another door out of frame to the left that's tall enough to admit the tractor, but the tractor's long enough to need to be under that truss, but too tall to fit. Yikes! I'd suggest "buy a smaller tractor", but what's the fun in that?? Going to have to echo others. This isn't a DIY job. At least not the design portion of it. The only way to totally DIY it that I see is to break up the floor and lower it - anything else will take a properly engineered solution and that takes somebody with the proper education, no matter how well intentioned we may be.

Comment: What part of the tractor hits the beam?

Answer (score 2):

DIY doesn't have to mean literally every step is done yourself -- it's entirely feasible to hire out the design and then do the construction yourself.

Consider a scissor style truss. It'll intersect with the post and beams at the same height as your existing truss while also allowing more clearance in the center of the building. It might be possible to modify the lower chord and webbing to convert your truss into a scissor truss.

The process could go something like this:

1. Hire engineer to design a new truss, whether factory-built or site built. The plywood gussets suggest to me that these trusses were site-built, but your new truss doesn't have to be. A truss manufacturing company will do the engineering as part of the price of the truss.
2. Erect a temporary structure to support the roof purlins on the far side of the existing truss. A "kicker" board under each might be sufficient; something more akin to a traditional wall with a sloping top plate surely would do.
3. If the new truss is a factory-built truss, bring it into the building and position it on the floor below the existing truss.
4. Erect support structure for the purlins on the near side of the existing truss.
5. Remove the existing truss, probably by disassembling it.
6. Install the new truss (or begin modifications of the remnants of the existing truss). If it's a factory-built you'll hoist or jack it up into place; if it's site-built then get the chop saw and nail gun warmed up!
7. Remove the temporary purlin supports.